# How to check if spark streaming job is running

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming job over YARN and want to add alerting in case the job terminates.

Is there a way to check if the job is running without using the pid (as it would keep on changing). I checked the output of `netstat -ntlp` once when the job was running and once when it was not. But there was no difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

When work with yarn cluster, you can set "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion" option to true and check your local spark-submit process.

**spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion true**

> In YARN cluster mode, controls whether the client waits to exit until
>   the application completes. If set to true, the client process will
>   stay alive reporting the application's status. Otherwise, the client
>   process will exit after submission.